# Bitmap not drawing in CFrameWnd's OnPaint

Tags: c++, mfc, bitmap

I can't seem to get the CBitmap to actually apear on the screen... Here's the code in OnPaint:

```
CRect frm;
GetClientRect(frm);

CClientDC dc(this);
//dc.FillSolidRect(CRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000), RGB(255, 255, 255));
CDC dcMem;
dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
CBitmap* cache = dcMem.SelectObject(&components.icon.bmp);

dc.BitBlt(0, 0, 55, 55, &dcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
dc.SelectObject(cache);
```

The definition of components.icon.bmp is...

```
components.icon.bmp.LoadBitmap(BMP_BOARDER);
BITMAP icon;
components.icon.bmp.GetBitmap(&icon);
```

There shouldn't be problem here. The Bitmap is a 32bit alpha bitmap and LoadBitmap returned TRUE.

It doesn't work with 24 bit either.

---- Got it! Problem with my resources

Comment: I didn't think GDI knew about 32 bit bitmaps.  I thought it only dealt with 24 bits.

Comment: Does LoadBitmap succeed (return TRUE)?

Comment: How do I go about ddrawing 32 bit bmps?

Comment: You could use GDI+.  It supports it.  Vanilla GDI does not, I don't think.

Comment: CFrameWnd's client area is usually occupied by views and toolbars

Comment: That's what Im trying to draw manually

Comment: Actually Im trying to draw the frame manually.

Comment: What are you trying to draw? You're trying to draw the frame while using a CClientDC?  Inside of OnPaint you should use CPaintDC. If you're trying to draw the non-client area, you might want to override WM_NCPAINT and then use a CWindowDC there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems good to me but there are still many things that can be wrong. Test your code to know where the problem is:
- If you draw anything else (a rectangle for instance) does it appears on the frame window?
- Try to save the bmp to a file and see if it's ok.
- Try to convert the bmp to 24bits using a tool and see if it works.

Once you know where the problem is you'll be able to focus on the problem.

Probably you won't be able to draw a 32bits bmp using GDI but you should get something (a black square at least). Anyway, if you need to draw 32bits alpha-channel bmps using GDI you have to pre-multiply the image and use `AlphaBlend` method instead of BitBlt.

Comment: I am able to draw Rectangles and primatives, but when I use the BitBlt fucntion, nothing seems to happen. Ill try wit 24 bits

Comment: I am getting these weird 'Debug Assertion Failed' error popups (two of them), but I just ignore them and the program runs.